# Python: is it possible to use list comprehension inside list declaration?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list:

```
t = ["3", "4", "5"]
```

Is it possible to include this list into another using list comprehension?
i.e.:

```
t2 = ["1", "2", x for x in t, "6", "7"]
```

with a result:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
```

Comment: Why not just concatenate the lists with `+`? Or you could use [`itertools.chain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/8204776).

Comment: You can do this (but probably shouldn't): `t2 = ["1", "2", *[x for x in t], "6", "7"]` You could also just use `t2 = ["1", "2", *t, "6", "7"]` if you had no processing to do.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It's fine to do that, I think. But it doesn't work in older python versions. And using a generator expression is sligthly more efficient, since you don't need to allocate memory for a temporary list. `["1", "2", *(x for x in t), "6"]` or simply `["1", "2", *t, "6"]`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog you're right, in my example it's easier to use concatenation, but in real task first list is not a list, it's a django queryset. Yes, querysets can be converted to list using list(t.values_list('field_name', flat = True)), but I was looking for more "elegant" way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with star unpacking.

Consider,

```
[1, 2, *[3, 4, 5], 6, 7]
```

this unpacks the `[3, 4, 5]` list into the outer list due to the `*`.

Therefore you can equally use a list-comprehension in lieu of this.

---

I.e.

```
t = ["3", "4", "5"]
t2 = ["1", "2", *[x for x in t], "6", "7"]
#["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
```

---

Note that, in Python versions `< 3.5`, iterable unpacking is not implemented.

Therefore as an alternative, you can use basic concatenation with the `+` operator:

```
t2 = ["1", "2"] + [x for x in t] + ["6", "7"]
```

Comment: Note that unpacking in list literals was added in python 3.5, so if you are using an older python version, you will have to concatenate lists using `+` instead.